# Is there any exponential function which returns IEEE_FLOAT64 in math.h header?

Tags: c++, c, math

I want to use exponential function which returns `IEEE_FLOAT64` value

Currently I am using `expf` function, but still I am getting lots of warnings.

```
value = IEEEPosOne - (IEEE_FLOAT64)expf(value1);
```

Comment: The 64-bit floating point number is exactly `double` in C/C++.

Comment: Use `exp()` for double, `expf()` for float, `expl()` for long double.

Comment: currently I am using expf(), But still I am getting loss of data warning

Comment: @iBug: Not true. Your implementation may be but that is not required by the standard.

Comment: then in what ways I can make this warning go away?

Comment: @MartinYork It's required in [N1570, § 7.12.6.1p1](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.12.6.1).

Comment: sorry But I didn't understand @MartinYork

Comment: @iBug: `double` is not required to be a 64-bit IEEE floating point number. (`exp` is required to return a `double` but that won't help if `double` has a different representation.)

Comment: CAAnusha: You get a loss of precision warning because you are supplying a `double` to a function whose argument is a `float` (that is, `expf`); converting `double` to `float` loses precision.

Comment: @iBug: You got a citation for that claim?

Comment: There does not to be *some* awareness that you are the only programmer in the entire planet that uses these identifiers.  This is now the ranking Google hit for "IEEEPosOne", the only other really relevant web page for "IEEE_FLOAT64" is one you also created.  Programmers should not define their own type system and expect help from a web site like this :)  Do show your definitions of these identifiers and the kind of C compiler and machine on which you use them.

Comment: @ibug: cppreference is an excellent resource but it is not definitive. In this case, it's not clear what "if supported" means; you are assuming it means "if supported by the hardware" but I believe that assumption is not warranted. What the standard says is that double must be a 64-bit IEEE float if the C implementation claims to support IEEE floats. The C implementation signals the support by defining the pp macro `__STDC_IEC_559__`. It is under no obligation to define that macro and if it doesn't, it has no obligation to use that float format. See Appendix F.

Comment: @rici Whooh! Thank you for your comprehensive explanation. I stand corrected.

Comment: @iBug 1) That is not the link to a standard.2) If it was that would be one that is way out of date as the last one was [c++17 -> n4660](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/prot/14882fdis/n4660.pdf) and the current draft is [n4727](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4727.pdf) 3)  There is no mention of IEEE in the standard (as the standard deliberately does not define implementation details).

Comment: @CAAnusha To test if your local implementation uses IEEE you need to do the following check. `std::numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559()` See: [iec559](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_iec559) This will be true if you are using IEEE. Then to see if you are using the 64 you need to check `size_of(double) == 64`. If both these are true you should be good (and they usually are).

Comment: @MartinYork: The standard says that if an implementation defines `iec559` to be true, it conforms to requirements for the floating-point standard, but not that, if an implementation conforms to the standard, it defines `iec559` to be true. So it is not a definitive test. And many implementations use IEEE-754 formats and behaviors but do not fully conform, so they do not define `iec559` to be true.

Comment: For calculating `1-exp(x)`, you should consider whether the specialized function `expm1` serves your purpose. It is intended to provide more accuracy when `x` is near zero.

Answer (score 1):

From `man 3 exp`:

```
NAME
       exp, expf, expl - base-e exponential function

SYNOPSIS
       #include <math.h>

       double exp(double x);
       float expf(float x);
       long double expl(long double x);

       Link with -lm.
```

So just use `exp()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
//c++
#include <cmath>
double x = 7.0;//float64
auto y = std::exp(x);//exp(float64);
```

C++ standard provides appropriate overloads. No need to reflect operand type in function name.

Comment: That last sentence is not really true. In C11, you can `#include <tgmath.h>` and then almost all math functions without a length indication (such as `exp`) will be overridden with macros which  automatically select the appropriate specific function.

Comment: Didn't know that. How does it deduce the type? Preprocessor should generally be unrelated to the type system. Big surprise to me.

Comment: The preprocessor is indeed unaware of the type system; the macros insert a generic selection expression. See section 6.5.1.1 (for example, [here](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.5.1.1) )

Comment: Found the keyword just now.

Answer (score 0):

This does answer does not apply to C only for C++
For C see @iBug's answer.

The C++ standard does not require an implementation to use the IEEE standard. Though this is usually the easiest floating point implementation to use as the chips are relatively standard in modern machines.

The standard provides a way to check using `std::numeric_limits`.

So if it is a requirement then you should validate.

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    static_assert(sizeof(double) == 64);
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559());

    // If the above compiles your double is IEEE 64 bit value.
    // Or IEEE_754 compliant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754_revision
}
```

Now that you have established you are using IEEE values you can look at the [cmath](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath) header to see that the functions there all take and return a double value.

- [exp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/exp)
- [log](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log)
- etc....

Note: You should note that Windows machines (usually) use an 80 bit floating point register (not 64). So things can get super whaky if you need strict compliance.

Note: **Do NOT use**:

- expf() for float,
- expl() for long double

These are for C library users where the language does not do the correct type checking. In C++ the language uses overloading to use the correct version of the function. If you look at the standard for `exp`:

Defined in header <cmath>

```
* float       exp( float arg );
* double      exp( double arg );
* long double exp( long double arg );
* double      exp( Integral arg );
```

The above are all in the standard namespace.

```
std::cout << std::exp(100000.1) << "\n";
```

Notice that `exp()` can take any floating point type `float`, `double` or `long double` and generate the appropriate result type.